# Jython zxJDBC cursor.tables() always returns None

Tags: jdbc, jython

I am using Jython 2.2.1 and MySQL Connector/J 5.1 to access a MySQL database.  I would like to use zxJDBC's cursor.tables() method to retrieve a list of tables in that database.  However, this method always returns *None*.

According to the zxJDBC documentation, cursor.tables() is the same as Java's DatabaseMetaData.getTables(). When I call this Java method from Jython, it works as expected, but using the zxJDBC package doesn't work for me. Here's what I have tried:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TableTest {
    public static void tables(String url) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", null);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = meta.getTables(null, null, "%",
                                          new String[] {"TABLE"});
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call this from Jython, it is all fine.

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
import TableTest

url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/jythontest'

print 'Java:'
TableTest.tables(url);

print 'Python:'
conn = zxJDBC.connect(url, 'root', None, 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print cursor.tables(None, None, '%', ('TABLE',))
```

There are two tables in my test database called 'table_a' and 'table_b'. The output is:

```
Java:
table_a
table_b
Python:
None
```

I have tried this on Linux and on MacOS with the same result. Before I try to figure out what's wrong with zxJDBC, I wanted to know whether there is anything wrong in the way I am using this package.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a print **cursor.fetchall()** after your cursor.tables()

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
import TableTest

url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/jythontest'

print 'Java:'
TableTest.tables(url);

print 'Python:'
conn = zxJDBC.connect(url, 'root', None, 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print cursor.tables(None, None, '%', ('TABLE',))
print cursor.fetchall()
```

*(tested with Informix and jython 2.5 beta)*

i assume:

- cursor.tables() excutes the query in
  python
- cursor.fetchall() returns the
  results